# Sum and product of roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Let's say we had a $n$th degree polynomial equation $a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0$, with $a$ being real coefficient. What would the sum and product of its roots be(in terms of $a$)? I think I got the product one but not the sum.

For the product:

Let's say the polynomial's roots are $r_1,r_2,r_3,\ldots,r_n$.

Then polynomial can be factored as:

$a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{a_n})(x-r_2)(x-r_3)\ldots(x-r_n)$

We can set this equal to original polynomial:

$a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{a_n})(x-r_2)(x-r_3)\ldots(x-r_n)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0$

Compare constant terms:

$a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ constant term=$a_0$.

$a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{a_n})(x-r_2)(x-r_3)\ldots(x-r_n)$ constant term=$(-1)^n*(\frac{r_1}{a_n})*r_2*r_3*\cdots*r_n$

$a_0=(-1)^n*(\frac{r_1}{a_n})*r_2*r_3*\cdots*r_n$

Multiply $(-1)^na_n$ both sides:

$r_1*r_2*r_3*\cdots r_n=(-1)^na_0a_n$

Is this correct? Also, what can I do for the sum of the roots(I think we use the coefficients of $x^{n-1}$)?

EDIT: J.W. Tanner has noted in [his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738109/sum-and-product-of-roots-of-a-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment7685979_3738109) that this is [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) which is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find.

Comment: $a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{an})$ should be $a_n(x-r_1)$

Comment: Cf. [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh thanks a lot! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n$ is not a root, it is the leading coefficient.

Imagine the polynomial $(x-2)(x-3) = x^2 - 5x + 6$.
The leading coefficient is $1$ but the roots are $2$ and $3$.

This part of your argument is incorrect.

> Then polynomial can be factored as:
>
> $a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{a_n})(x-r_2)(x-r_3)\ldots(x-r_n)$

It should read this.

> Then polynomial can be factored as:
>
> $a_n(x-{r_1})(x-r_2)(x-r_3)\ldots(x-r_n)$

From this representation it gets obvious that the free term is

$a_n(-1)^nr_1 r_2 ... r_n$

But on the other hand we know it is $a_0$.

So the product of the roots must be:

$$\frac{a_0}{(-1)^na_n} = (-1)^n \cdot \frac{a_0}{a_n} $$

For calculating the sum of the roots just compare the coefficient before $x^{n-1}$.
You will get that the sum of the roots equals $$-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$

See also: [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)